# Java not found by Jenkins slave

Tags: java, windows-xp, jenkins

I had this XP machine configured correctly as a Jenkins slave. But now...

When I try to launch the node, I get 
No Java found, downloading JDK and then it fails

I do have java installed, as the slave worked before.
On the slave machine console, I can run java and it finds it OK
I added JAVA_HOME with the correct path to the slave configuration screen. 
No luck.

Thoughts?

Comment: What did you change just before the slave stopped working ?  Are you running the slave as a Windows service ?

Comment: it is running as Windows service. Not sure what changed, it is managed by IT :( Windows update is the only thing I can think of

Comment: the command that runs, on a successful Jenkins slave is java -version.  This is the command that fails on the bad slave. I also installed the latest JDK, no change.

Comment: on the bad slave console, I can run java -version. How does the system know where java is installed. I do not have the c:\p...\jre7\bin in the path at all and no JAVA_HOME is defined

Comment: I'm just wondering if the Windows service runs as a different user from the one that you're logging onto the slave with and running "java -version".  If so, it may not have its PATH set to find java.exe correctly.

Comment: Jenkins and interactive login user as the same

Comment: Can you post the error message you get from Jenkins when it tries to start the slave ?

Comment: Connecting to 172.27.13.144
Checking if Java exists
ERROR: Failed to prepare Java
jcifs.smb.SmbException: The system cannot find the file specified.
 at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:545)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:622)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:244)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:770)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:139)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbNamedPipe.getNamedPipeOutputStream(SmbNamedPipe.java:189)
 at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

latest upgrade to Jenkins eliminated this problem.

Comment: one other oddity i've found with jenkins is that if you create a new jenkins instance where you have "automatically install" for stuff like a JDK/ANT/etc that leaving the setting as "Default" for your job doesn't work if you set up that job *before* the app tries to install the dependent software. if memory serves the fix i've found is to manually select the JDK in the job as opposed to just leaving it as "Default"

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if this is due to inconsistent use of 32 bit vs. 64 bit processes in certain versions of Windows.  I found [this issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-6957) in the Jenkins JIRA which has some suggested workarounds for your error - give it a try and let me know if any of them work.